# Speed-up lookup of a row with prefix pattern

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance

Say I have these rows in one `UNIQUE` column:

- 202101XXXXX
- 202101XXXXX
- 202102XXXXX
- 202102XXXXX
- 202103XXXXX
- 202103XXXXX

The first 6 digits are year and month (YYYYMM), and the XXXXX part are random digits. They are `UNIQUE`. Let's say there are millions of rows like these.

I need to lookup a certain row e.g., `20210312345`, is there a way I could tell MySQL to not look at the whole table and just search on rows with the `202103` prefix? And, if that was possible, would it actually speed up the query?

Comment: If you index your entire field, then searching by the first n characters (s.t. n <= 10) should be [sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable)! No requirement for a `GENERATED` column **unless** you might want to filter on your XXXXX suffix? You'll have a maximum of 99,999 possible suffixes for all your data for XXXXX to be `UNIQUE` - or do you only mean `UNIQUE` within a given year/month combination?

Comment: @Vérace The whole column contains `202101XXXXX` which is "indexed" as `UNIQUE`. That said, I don't need to do anything anymore since it's "sargable"?

Comment: So, you can have 201005ABCDEF and 201006ABCDEF? Sargable means that the RDBMS can take advantage of an index on that field if you use `LIKE '2010%' - i.e. if the suffix is searched, that's find, but if it's one of the XXXXX's, then you have put an index on a `GENERATED` column.

Comment: @Vérace Yes you can have those values.

Answer (score 0):

This is how indexing essentially works. If you create an index on that column, the data will be sorted by the value, which effectively is on the prefix first and then the suffix.

The other thing you can do is either store only the suffix part (the XXXXX) of the value in it's own column too, either from the application that loads the data or using a [**Stored Generated Column**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) and then create the index on that field. Doing that allows you to do an exact match search on a more unique value.

Comment: On the first part of your answer, since the column is already `UNIQUE`, safe to say MySQL already does what I describe? Note the whole item `20210312345` is currently in just one column that is `UNIQUE`.

Comment: @IMB - A `UNIQUE` is an `INDEX`.  So, what you have is perfectly good already.  There would be no noticeable speed advantage if you could skip over the prefix.

Comment: @RickJames Got it thanks